# Python, ProjectEuler, Optimization makes code slower

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I used the following code to tackle Project Euler question 14. For those who don't know this question, I have to find the number below one million with the largest number of "steps" in its Collatz sequence.

```
largen = 0

for i in range (1, 1000000):
    n = 0
    k = i
    while k != 1:

        if k % 2 == 0:
            k = k/2
            n = n+1


        else:
            k = 3*k+1
            n = n+1

    if n > largen:
        largen = n
        answer = i


print "Value with highest number of terms in collatz sequence is %d which has %d terms in its collatz sequence." % (answer, largen)
```

This gives me the correct answer in about 1m20s. However I thought I could speed this up by in the following way. First I instructed the program to remember the number of steps in the collatz sequence for each value i. Then, if during the process of finding the sequence for a number k, I land on a previous number i I've calculated the sequence for, I would just add the number of terms in the sequence for i to the number I've calculated so far for k.

For example, let's say I'm trying to calculate the number of steps in the sequence for 13. The first 3 steps are 13-40-20-10. Now I've already calculated that the number of steps in the sequence for 10 is 6 (10-5-16-8-4-2-1). So the number of steps in the sequence for 13 is the 3 taken to get to 10 added to the 6 needed to get from 10 to 1, i.e. a total of 9 steps.

To this end, I modified the code to the following:

```
nterms = [] # for each value i, contains number of terms in collatz sequence
used = [] # list of used values of i (so can add nterms[i-1] to collatz sequence which redirects to i)

largen = 0

for i in range (1, 1000000):

    n = 0
    k = i
    while k != 1:

        if k in used:
            n = n+nterms[k-1]
            break

        elif k % 2 == 0:
            k = k/2
            n = n+1

        else:
            k = 3*k+1
            n = n+1

    if n > largen:
        largen = n
        answer = i

    used.append(i)
    nterms.append(n)

print "Value with highest number of terms in collatz sequence is %d which has %d terms in its collatz sequence." % (answer, largen)
```

However when I try and run this I get MemoryError outprinted to the terminal screen. When I try with smaller values (i.e. up to 10000) I get the same answer as my original piece of code but much more slowly (i.e. takes 7 seconds as opposed to 1 second).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Use a `set` for `used`, not a `list`! Or even better, don't use `used` at all and replace `if k in used` by `if k < i`.

Answer (score 1):

The thought of optimization is fine, but you chose the wrong data structure.

```
nterms = []
used = []
```

These two lists are used to store the Collatz sequence that you already calculated, right? But to find an element in a list, the time complexity is O(n), which is not efficient enough.

---

Instead, try using a dictionary, the numbers are the keys, and their number of Collatz sequence as the values. For example, the key `10` has a value of `6`.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if `k` can be found from `used` slows down the computation since checking if element can be found from list has **O(n)** time complexity.

Instead of using two lists you could only use one that initially has `1000000` elements which are all initialized to `-1`. Then on every iteration once you know the Collatz number you update it to the respective index so that you can use it later:

```
largen = 0
answer = 0
memo = [-1] * 1000000
for i in xrange(1, 1000000):
    n = 0
    k = i
    while k != 1:
        # Since k can grow from original need to check it's within bounds
        if k < 1000000 and memo[k] != -1:
            n += memo[k]
            break
        if k % 2 == 0:
            k /= 2
        else:
            k = 3 * k + 1

        n += 1

    memo[i] = n
    if n > largen:
        largen = n
        answer = i
```

Compared to the dictionary cache this approach is about 10-15% faster on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Looking up an element in a list is a O(n) operation, which may become pretty  slow for large lists. A dictionary, on the other hand, guarantees a constant lookup time complexity (O(1)):

```
cache = {}

for i in range (1, 1000000):
    n = 0
    k = i
    while k != 1:

        if k in cache:
            n = n + cache[k]
            break

        if k % 2 == 0:
            k = k/2
            n = n+1


        else:
            k = 3*k+1
            n = n+1


    cache[i] = n
    if n > largen:
        largen = n
        answer = i


print "Value with highest number of terms in collatz sequence is %d which has %d terms in its collatz sequence." % (answer, largen)
```

On my machine, this approach speeds up the solution by a factor of about 13, from ~26 seconds for the OP to ~2 seconds for the one presented in this answer.